# Animated film/show with man's journey of reverse civilization to an extent that he goes naked and hunts for food

Tags: animation, story-identification

I remember watching an animated film or an episode from an animated TV show (maybe anthology) on Indian channel [Doordarshan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doordarshan) aka DD1 in mid 90s but the movie or show appears to be little older as foreign animation takes time to come to India back then. So my bets are 80s or early 90s.

**Plot:**

Main character is a man who is too dependent on machine that he doesn't even move a single foot at all and all of his work is done by remote control machines by using a remote control. Like he was automatically sent from a recliner/sofa to a shower and then back to sofa. From brushing to applying soap all done by automatic machines.

Then one day he dropped his remote and was too lazy to even pick it up and also power goes out somehow ( [AJ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37458196#37458196) reminded me that part).

Then it's winter outside and his whole house got covered in snow from outside. I think he didn't move at all in winter but when he did. He tried to open the door and windows but having difficulty due to snow.

When he goes out it was summer outside. He removed all his clothes and gone naked with exposing his private parts and pubic hair and armpit hairs too (That was a surprise as we have strict censorship regarding nudity in India). Then he became like a cavemen and made cloth out of a carpet by making a hole for his head. To feed himself he went for hunting animals.

**Ending:**

I am not sure about the ending, it either ends with him being able to survive without machine and his new wildlife side or it all turns out to be a dream while he was sitting on a sofa.

**Release/Broadcast year:**

Not sure but I guess mid 80s to early 90s.

**Country:**

It appears western to me, so maybe US, Canada or UK but not sure. Most probably not an anime.

**Language:**

I think English but not sure as there were no words said or very minimal.

**Colour/Black and White:**

I think it was coloured.

**Style**

2D, animation style looks similar to The Pink Panther

Comment: Sounds a lot like an episode of the short animations in the "Hamilton Ham and Hattie" series by United Productions of America (UPA), one of the small prolific studios in the late 50s/early 60s, which were global TV fillers for decades. The character Ham was depicted as an actor who would perform skits with a moral lesson, while Hattie was a little girl with poetic inclinations commenting on her world and emotions about it. I could imagine Hamilton Ham doing such a parable about technology.

Comment: If it has nudity it is more likely European.